# Merging the multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have a dataframe like this (actual data has 70 columns with timestamp) with Column name as A_Timestamp, BC_Timestamp, DA_Timestamp, CA_Timestamp, B_Values, C_values, D_Values, Q_Values

| A_Timestamp | B_Values |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-11-08 11:15:00 | 1 |
| 2020-11-10 15:34:00 | 2 |

| BC_Timestamp | C_Values |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-11-11 12:13:00 | 8 |
| 2020-11-15 02:47:00 | 4 |

| DA_Timestamp | D_Values |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-1-13 14:47:00 | 3 |
| 2020-11-9 5:34:00 | 5 |

| CA_Timestamp | Q_Values |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-7-18 01:04:00 | 7 |
| 2020-04-10 16:34:00 | 6 |

And I want Like this:

| Timestamp          |          |B_Values| C_values| D_values| Q_Values|

| 2020-11-08 11:15:00 |    1  |       Nan  |    Nan  |    Nan|

| 2020-11-10 15:34:00 |   2    |     Nan   |   Nan  |    Nan |

| 2020-11-11 12:13:00 |   Nan  |      8    |   Nan    |  Nan|

| 2020-11-15 02:47:00 |   Nan   |     4    |   Nan   |   Nan|

| 2020-1-13 14:47:00  |    Nan  |     Nan    |   3    |   Nan|

| 2020-11-9 05:34:00  |    Nan  |     Nan    |   5  |     Nan|

| 2020-7-18 01:04:00  |  Nan   |    Nan     |  Nan   |   7|

I want to merge all the columns ending with 'Timestamp' into one single column. And each timestamp with their respective value in the respective columns.

Comment: In your example you have 4 inputs, if this is not the case, please clarify with a DataFrame constructor

Comment: Please provide the code [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a renamer for the Timestamp column:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4]

renamer = lambda x: 'Timestamp' if x.endswith('Timestamp') else x
out = pd.concat([d.rename(renamer, axis=1) for d in dfs])
```

Output:

```
             Timestamp  B_Values  C_Values  D_Values  Q_Values
0  2020-11-08 11:15:00       1.0       NaN       NaN       NaN
1  2020-11-10 15:34:00       2.0       NaN       NaN       NaN
0  2020-11-11 12:13:00       NaN       8.0       NaN       NaN
1  2020-11-15 02:47:00       NaN       4.0       NaN       NaN
0   2020-1-13 14:47:00       NaN       NaN       3.0       NaN
1    2020-11-9 5:34:00       NaN       NaN       5.0       NaN
0   2020-7-18 01:04:00       NaN       NaN       NaN       7.0
1  2020-04-10 16:34:00       NaN       NaN       NaN       6.0
```

##### alternative

Assuming you have a single DataFrame as input:

```
           A_Timestamp  B_Values         BC_Timestamp  C_Values        DA_Timestamp  D_Values         CA_Timestamp  Q_Values
0  2020-11-08 11:15:00         1  2020-11-11 12:13:00         8  2020-1-13 14:47:00         3   2020-7-18 01:04:00         7
1  2020-11-10 15:34:00         2  2020-11-15 02:47:00         4   2020-11-9 5:34:00         5  2020-04-10 16:34:00         6
```

You can then reshape with a MultiIndex:

```
m = df.columns.str.endswith('Timestamp')
s = df.columns.to_series().mask(m)

out = (df
   .set_axis(pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
             [s.bfill(), s.fillna('Timestamp')]), axis=1)
   .T.stack().unstack(-2).droplevel(0)
)
```

Output:

```
  B_Values C_Values D_Values Q_Values            Timestamp
0        1      NaN      NaN      NaN  2020-11-08 11:15:00
1        2      NaN      NaN      NaN  2020-11-10 15:34:00
0      NaN        8      NaN      NaN  2020-11-11 12:13:00
1      NaN        4      NaN      NaN  2020-11-15 02:47:00
0      NaN      NaN        3      NaN   2020-1-13 14:47:00
1      NaN      NaN        5      NaN    2020-11-9 5:34:00
0      NaN      NaN      NaN        7   2020-7-18 01:04:00
1      NaN      NaN      NaN        6  2020-04-10 16:34:00
```

Or, if order of the rows doesn't matter:

```
m = df.columns.str.endswith('Timestamp')
s = df.columns.to_series().mask(m)

(df.set_axis(pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
             [s.fillna('Timestamp'), s.bfill()]), axis=1)
   .stack()
)
```

Comment: It is one DataFrame, not list of DataFrames.

Comment: @jezrael then OP should provide the said dataframe as one block, the question clearly used 4 different tables (see my comment)